# mount: /: mount point not mounted or bad option (fresh Gentoo installation)

Tags: boot, fstab, gentoo, root-filesystem, read-write

Just rebooted gentoo install from livecd, and it seems like nothing is writable. On boot I get this error as it tries to remount the root filesystem read/write:

```
mount: /: mount point not mounted or bad option
Root filesystem could not be mounted read/write
```

My wifi interface also failed to start, but I think I know how to fix it... If the root filesystem worked.

Also here is my /etc/fstab:

```
dev/nvme0n1p1     /boot     vfat     defaults     2 0
dev/nvme0n1p5     none      swap     sw           0 0
dev/nvme0n1p6     /         ext4     noatime      0 0
```

So far I've tried to unmount dev/nvme0n1p6 and remount it as write, but it always gives me /dev/nvme0n1p6 already mounted to /. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the `remount` option. `man mount`. `sudo mount -o remount,rw,noatime /dev/nvme0n1p6 /`

Comment: Works temporarily, but before reboot I get error 
`Failed to save random seed`
`ERROR: urandom failed to stop`
and then
`Remounting remaining filesystems read-only ...`
`Remounting / read only...`
Then I have the same issue again once I boot in.

Comment: That's because system shutdown unmounts your `rw` mount, along with everything else, except the `ro` `/`, and, later tries to save the random seed.   Look at, and repair the line in `/etc/fstab` that specifies `/`. Read `man -a  mount;man -a fstab`. Having `/` come up as `ro` could be symptomatic of a bad or incomplete install.